# Need help fixing the while loop

Tags: java, string, while-loop, int

Hi i was trying to create a mock database search and, though it works, whenever i enter an input that is not part of the database, it creates an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 on line 23. I dont know what else to do as i see no error in the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Database {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] names = new String[4];

    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;
    names[0] = "Thor";
    names[1] = "Ben";
    names[2] = "Zoe";
    names[3] = "Kate";

    System.out.println("Enter Player Name");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    while(found != true){

        if(input.equals(names[i])){
            System.out.println(input + " has been found");
            found = true;
        } else {
            i = i+1;
        }
        if(i == 3 && found == false){
            System.out.println(input + " was not found");
        }

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: BTW you can do `i++` (instead of `i = i + 1`) and `!found` (instead of `found == false`);

Answer (score 1):

You are not leaving the loop after you print that `input + " was not found"`.
Therefore the next iteration of the loop throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should leave the loop after you finish testing the entire array.

change

```
    while(found != true){
```

to

```
    while(!found && i < names.length){
```

Actually you can move the if statement that tests whether the input wasn't found to be after the loop :

```
  while(!found && i < names.length) {
    if(input.equals(names[i])){
        System.out.println(input + " has been found");
        found = true;
    } else {
        i = i+1;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
      System.out.println(input + " was not found");
  }
```

An even better alternative would be to use a for loop :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < names.length && !found; i++) {
    if(input.equals(names[i])){
        System.out.println(input + " has been found");
        found = true;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
      System.out.println(input + " was not found");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked an absolute treat. I will keep it in mind for my complete database. This one was a practice to test out the concepts needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to

```
    while (found != true) {

        if (input.equals(names[i])) {
            System.out.println(input + " has been found");
            found = true;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (i == 4 && found == false) {   //changed here

            System.out.println(input + " was not found");
            //or found == true;
            break;           //and here
        }

    }
```

You need to quit the loop if THIS condition is true

```
i == 4 && found == false
```

and to actually quit, you must "break" the while condition

```
found != true
```

You can do this by setting `found=true` (but that's not semantically correct) or add the `break` instruction.

Here is an alternative solution to your while loop:

```
    while (!found && i<4) 
        if (input.equals(names[i++]))found = true;
    System.out.println(input+(found?" has been":" was not")+" found");
```

Answer (score 0):

if your input doesn't matches the value of i will keep on incrementing and your length of an array is 4. Obviously ArrayindexoutofException.
To avoid you need to consider the array length also.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change to

```
while(i < names.length)
```

and forget the additional boolean variable. Since you want to keep iterating `i` until you find the solution, the stop condition will be the max i. When you do find your solution, you can simply `break`the while statement:

```
if (input.equals(names[i])) {
    System.out.println(input + " has been found");
    break;
}
```